# Shipit Fedex Module Error: Invalid Reply

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can any one help me on this please,

I'm new in nodejs, here I'm using shipit module for tacking.
I have FedEx Test credentials but when I try to request with fedex test tracking numbers its throwing an Invalid Reply error.

Comment: That's not enough info. Where's the code? Where's the stack trace?

Comment: fedex = new FedexClient({
    key: 'xxx', 
    password: 'xxxxx', 
    account: 'xxx', 
    meter: 'xxxx'});
fedex.requestData({trackingNumber: '338546050904603'}, function(err, result) {
    if(err!==null){
      node.log("Error :"+ err);
    }if(result!==null){
     node.log("Result :" + result);
    }
});

Comment: can any one please help me on this

Comment: The code, along with error messages, which you didn't post, and stack traces goes with the post, not as a comment